# PowerShell hash table conditional assignment

Tags: powershell

I have this hash table in a PowerShell script (shortened with a few examples but contains about 8 or so items in it):
--Code previous to this hash table builds the $i variable so I will just supply it for this example of what it should be. It is dependent upon what edition of SQL is on the server. So SQL 2008 R2 default instance would be "MSSQL10_50.MSSQLServer".

```
$i = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER'
$SQLPaths = @{
   'DefaultData'=(Get-ItemProperty "$i\MSSQLServer").DefaultLog;
   'RepWorking'=(Get-ItemProperty "$i\Replication").WorkingDirectory
}
```

My question/issue...Is there a shortcut way of testing this registry path (Test-Path) within the hash table before it sets the value, or tries to? I have some keys just like this that if the feature or setting was never set then the key will not actually exist. Which is fine but how can I ignore it if it does not, and just let the value be null in the hash table?

Comment: What value would be added to the hash table if the key does not exist? (I can see a solution if the answer isn't "don't add the key.)

Comment: They all contain directory paths for various locations of SQL Server configuration and user files.

Comment: Try #2: you want to test the registry path before setting the hash value. But what to do if the test *fails* (path doesn't exist)?

Comment: ah, sorry read it to quickly...setting it to NULL is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PowerShell the `if` statement can be used as an expression:

```
$i = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER'
$SQLPaths = @{
   'DefaultData'= if (Test-Path "$i\MSSQLServer") { 
                     (Get-ItemProperty "$i\MSSQLServer").DefaultLog
                  } else {
                     $null
                  };
   'RepWorking'=(Get-ItemProperty "$i\Replication").WorkingDirectory
}
```

Also if you're using the [PowerShell Community Extensions](http://pscx.codeplex.com/) (PSCX) it adds a `Invoke-Ternary` (alias `?:`) function which could make this less verbose:

```
$i = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER'
$SQLPaths = @{
   'DefaultData'= ?: {Test-Path "$i\MSSQLServer"} `
                     { (Get-ItemProperty "$i\MSSQLServer").DefaultLog } `
                     { $null };
   'RepWorking'=(Get-ItemProperty "$i\Replication").WorkingDirectory
}
```

Comment: I would actually need to test the path down to the registry key. $i\MSSQLServer will exist but the registry key itself might not.

Comment: Ah never mind, just found that Test-Path is not capable of checking if registry key exist...oh well.

Comment: work around I believe if ((Get-ItemProperty "$i\MSSQLServer").DefaultLog -ne $null) {get value} else {$null}

Comment: `Test-Path` certainly works with the registry here. But note it will test registry *keys*. To check a value you need to use `Test-Path` on the containing key, and then see if `Get-ItemProperty` on the value (normally it would fail but adding `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` will lead to a `$null`). Of course as this logic is non-trivial it can be wrapped in a re-usable function.

Comment: I found out the replication portion, $i\Replication, will not exist at all so just doing Test-Path on it works well. Apparently if you do Get-ItemProperty on a registry entry and it does not exist, it will return $null by default, it will not show any errors. Which the $i\MSSQLServer will always exist on servers with SQL Server installed. So the only one I have to worry about is replication, and then if I check for SSRS. Thanks.